# Is there a simple way to comment out or diable a python try statement without re-indenting

Tags: python, exception

**Problem:**
Sometimes it is nice to be able to remove or apply a try statement temporarily.  Is there a convenient way to disable the try statement without re-indenting?

For example, if there was a python block statement equivalent called "goForIt:"  one could edit the word "try:" to "goForIt:" and it would just execute the block as though it were not wrapped in a "try" and ignore the "except" line too.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that while I want the try statement in production I want to be able to remove it temporarily while debugging to see the error traceback rather than have it trap and process the exception.

Currently I work around this by commenting out the "try" then re-indent the code in the block.  Then comment out the entire "except" block.   This seems clumsy.

Comment: You could replace the `try:` with `if True:` and the `except ...` with `if False:` (or even just `if 1:` and `if 0:`). When I say "replace", I mean, comment out and add the other line after it, as it's quicker to revert afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing the try, you could make the `except` re-raise the exception:

```
try:
    raise ValueError('whoops')
except ValueError as e:
    raise # <-- just put this here
    print('caught')
```

This will raise the error, just as if it were not caught:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-a6be6779c161> in <module>
      1 try:
----> 2     raise ValueError('whoops')
      3 except ValueError as e:
      4     raise
      5     print('caught')

ValueError: whoops
```

Comment: after looking at everything this is the best

Answer (score 1):

*(This is not my answer, but the answer from Alani's comment. If credits, find the original comment under the question.)*

The solution is good because it allows global replacement:

```
try: --> if 1: # try:
except --> if 0: # except
```

The 2nd one is a little unsure. Exact and full word match should be used, or replace twice (for `except<space>` and `except:`). Or you can fix error fast by hand if there is any.
The replacement back is sure.

I need now such solution to debug error in strawberry which is only printed. So I think I need deactivate all try/except structures in 3 libraries (strawberry + 2 libs for django).

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a way to fix this.

Is it adequate to catch the exception, print it out and, if wanted, end the program?

```
try:
  # code
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
  # end program if wanted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a none code solution you need to use an IDE or a good text editor.
I am using Visual Studio code where I can indent with a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + ` in my case)